# Does door jamb size make a difference in installation?

Tags: doors, exterior

How can I install a 34 inch door made for a 4 inch door jamb in to a 6 inch door jamb. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set the door flush to the exterior. Google "jamb extension" for the rest. (Your jamb extensions will probably be 2", so likely to require ripping.)